# Xcode 7 fails with Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am going through the process of updating my swift project to Swift 2.0 on Xcode 7. The following error is being reported by xcode on building the project:

`Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

This happens on either SwiftyJSON or SwiftSpinner frameworks (the compiler seems to pick one first at random and fail, so the error gets reported intermittently on either or the other). I have updated these frameworks to their xcode7/swift2 compatible branches but the project still fails to compile.

Just wondering if this is a situation other people are seeing when upgrading their project with cocoa pods framework dependencies, or if this is a compiler bug

Comment: I manage to fix this, somewhere in my code is not doing right and one of my library is not existing. So I recommend to check the log and what it say then fix it

Comment: @CaffeineShots Please elaborate a bit more on how to found the cause of the error? I all the text before the error line I see no indications on what the cause of my problem could be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For others with a similar problem try this:
Open Console (not terminal) and choose All Messages. Then try to build your Xcode project and when it fails take a look in the list there with any message that could be related to Xcode.

I found a message like this:

> 01/10/15 10.24.17,808 Xcode[53145]:  DVTAssertions: Warning in
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-8228/IDEFoundation/Playgrounds/IDEPlaygroundAuxiliarySourceCompilerOperation.m:311
>   Details:  Unable to read diagnostics from file
>   "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OurProject-diexylwajzhwgtfqdwiphjgzdwcy/Build/Intermediates/OurProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/OurProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CheckoutUserDataAdapter.dia"
>   (Invalid File): Invalid diagnostics signature Function: void
>   XCGenerateDiagnosticsFromFile(NSString *__strong, NSString *__strong,
>   NSDictionary *__strong, NSDictionary *__strong,
>   IDEActivityLogSectionRecorder *__strong, BOOL
>   (^__strong)(IDEActivityLogMessage *__strong)) Thread:   {number = 250, name = (null)} Please file a bug at
>   http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful
>   information you can provide.

This gave us info that the error was in CheckoutUserDataAdapter.swift.
After trial and error we found that the problem was it was calling a method from its super class that it overrides from its super class. Somehow it could not find the correct method. 
We fixed it by adding super.methodCall() in CheckoutUserDataAdapter.swift - but that of cause should not be needed. I have filed a bug report.

Comment: i just notice that you tag me yesterday sorry for late reply. In my end i have this file which i include to my project but actually just made reference to that file locally not include it to my sandbox.

Comment: @Morten, where in the error message do you see a reference to your .swift file?

Comment: @LuisDelgado .../Objects-normal/armv7/CheckoutUserDataAdapter.dia - I know I have a swift file with the same name

Comment: I've located the file where to fix the issue using @MortenHolmgaard 's solution and after trial and error managed to find out that the problem was a nested function with default values for certain parameters. As soon as the default parameters were removed, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

Check Build Phases - Compile Sources for deleted files, or files with a blank icon, once this file was removed the error was gone

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Dug for the Build Phase tip. I ended up going a different direction than the deletion...

After checking Build Phases - Compile Sources, find the files that are grayed out (don't currently have a link to an actual file) to identify the files in question.

If the files are still being used, then find them in the Project Navigator (left hand column) and you'll see that they're colored red because Xcode only has a reference and not a location for the actual file.

Select each red file and then head to the File Inspector (right hand column). You'll see "Location". Locate your files by clicking the gray folder and finding them in the file structure outside of Xcode.

If you're working with a repo, you may find it easier to simply remove the red files, choose File > Add Files to... and simply re-add them so the link is more generic rather than pointing directly to your machine's file location.

This happened to me after a project file merge in which I'd been branched from the main repo for quite a while so a handful of file locations were lost in the merge.